# Rails 4 & Compass: can't route to precompiled image in production from css

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, compass-sass

When I'm launching my Rails 4 app in development mode – everything works fine, but when I'm trying to precompile assets and then run it in production – my images couldn't be founded on a server.

The problem is in the image request url: it has no fingerprint on the end.
For example, my precompiled image lay at the `/assets/image-12rfh98hf734hgf973.png` and the request is just the `/assets/image.png`.

So, the question is how do I write my code inside sass file's to route the correct image?

My gemfile is

```
gem 'rails', '4.0.1'
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 4.0.0'
gem "compass-rails"
gem 'haml-rails'
```

I'm trying this code, but it doesn't produce fingerprint in compiled css:

```
@include background(image-url("baloon_big.png"));
```

and some variations of `image-url`, like `image-path`, `image_path` etc.

In Rails 3 I hadn't faced this problem, so may be the problem is in the gems.

Thanks in advance.

EDIT

Figured out that problem is only in my work machine – I'm deployed my app to heroku and paths resolving fine (with fingerprints). The question is still open – what's wrong with me (and my computer).

Comment: have you tried `url( asset-path("balloon_big.png"), image)` which worked for me using `css.sass``

Comment: Nope, it doesn't. However, I'm using scss and switching to sass is not the solution.